# The function 'setState' isn't defined. Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to spawn a dropdown menu to select values, I've made sure everything is stateful but Setstate doesn't like it still.

Tried wrapping it in different widgets or using different dropdown properties. still doesn't want to work it seems.

```
class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override

  _DicePageState createState() => new _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: BodyLayout(),
    );
  }
}

class BodyLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  BodyLayout({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BodyLayoutState createState()=> _BodyLayoutState();
}

class _BodyLayoutState extends State<BodyLayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return _myListView(ctxt);
  }
}




Widget _myListView(BuildContext ctxt) {

  final List<String> entries = <String>['A','B','C'];
  final List<int> colorCodes = <int>[600, 500, 100];

  return ListView.separated(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    itemCount: entries.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
      return Container(
        height: 150,
        color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownValue = newValue;
                });
              },
              items: <String>['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            ),
            new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: new MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('2'),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: new IconButton(
                iconSize: 80,
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.casino),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      );
    },
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) => const Divider(),
  );
}
```

Expected it to spawn a listed dropdown menu on button click.

Comment: Did you extend stateful widget?

Comment: it is working perfectly. do you want to change only at one place at a time?

Comment: Is your function part of a stateful widget?

Comment: I've added the rest of the file code above the original function. As far as I can tell everything is stateful for this particular page. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Answered, the function must be created under a stateful widget, not just called. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Trying your code, it will actually get the error:

> The function 'setState' isn't defined.

If you call setState outside, there is no way for flutter to recognize on which state should be updated.

You should have the `_myListView` method inside the `BodyLayout` class, as that has to do with the state.

Here is an updated code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => new _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: BodyLayout(),
    );
  }
}

class BodyLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  BodyLayout({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BodyLayoutState createState() => _BodyLayoutState();
}

class _BodyLayoutState extends State<BodyLayout> {
  String dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return _myListView(ctxt);
  }

  Widget _myListView(BuildContext ctxt) {
    final List<String> entries = <String>['A', 'B', 'C'];
    final List<int> colorCodes = <int>[600, 500, 100];

    return ListView.separated(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      itemCount: entries.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
        return Container(
            height: 150,
            color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                new SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: <String>[
                      '1',
                      '2',
                      '3',
                      '4',
                      '5',
                      '6',
                      '7',
                      '8',
                      '9',
                      '10'
                    ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: new MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('2'),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: new IconButton(
                    iconSize: 80,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.casino),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ));
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) => const Divider(),
    );
  }
}
```